# Download a video from URL that doesn't end in .mp4 - Python

Tags: python, python-requests

I'm trying to download a video from TikTok using the *requests* library, but the output file is always 1KB. Maybe it's bacause it doesnt end in the .mp4 extension in the url, but if I copy and paste it in my browser, the video plays fine.

```
import requests

url = 'https://v16-web.tiktok.com/video/tos/useast2a/tos-useast2a-ve-0068c004/0ba151caee14446eab001fb3ccc80481/?a=1988&br=2336&bt=1168&cd=0%7C0%7C1&ch=0&cr=0&cs=0&cv=1&dr=0&ds=3&er=&expire=1636927762&ft=wUyFfFxrkag3-I&l=2021111416083401018907207204E97E43&lr=tiktok_m&mime_type=video_mp4&net=0&pl=0&policy=3&qs=0&rc=MzlqPDY6ZnE2OTMzNzczM0ApZjs3aDg0Zzw4NzQ5ZzpnNGdgMGgvcjRvLzVgLS1kMTZzczEvYzVgYi5iLTEyYi1fYWA6Yw%3D%3D&signature=21d4211038dc54aa92bf68fcc9e71a34&tk=0&vl=&vr='
with open('video.mp4', 'wb') as out_file:
    content = requests.get(url, stream=True).content
    out_file.write(content)
```

Comment: Use a text editor to see what's in that 1kb file

Comment: What's in the file!?

Comment: for me that url 403s, i.e. 'not authenticated'.  You might want to try [a library](https://pypi.org/project/TikTokApi/). (note that I have no experience with either tiktok or this library)

Comment: Yeah, you are right. Opening the file with Notepad shows that. But I still could watch if I open with an Incognito tab.

Comment: You might wanna capture and send cookies

Comment: @TheMaster I have no ideia how to do that. :D